# in sentiment analysis of twitter data, repeated retweets infulence the result?

Tags: r, twitter, sentiment-analysis, data-cleaning

I am doing sentiment analysis of twitter data in r. But have more repeated tweets in data. **is it affect the result?**

> RT @Ananduvi: Will You Support #BharathBandh on Today against #demonetization ???
>
> RT @Ananduvi: Will You Support #BharathBandh on Today against #demonetization ???

if yes! then how to deal with it.? i wanna remove that tweets from twitter dataset.

```
text<- gsub("(RT|via)((?:\\b\\W*@\\w+)+ )", "", text)
```

This code removes only name of person but tweet remains as it is.

I will be glad if you help me.

Comment: Definitely it will affect the result. We can check the tweet Id associated with every tweet. Remove the duplicate Id's.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tweets repeated, it will skew the analytics!

With the Twitter API you have Tweets returned in JSON format - you need to treat the "id" field (or better the "id_str" field) from the Tweet as the unique identifier and only select single instances of a given "id" in your analytics.

```
{"id": 123456789, "id_str": "123456789"}
```

If you make sure you only have one instance of each tweet keyed on the field above, you will avoid this problem.